# some selected fields as Pivote column ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pivot, pivot-table

I want to show some selected columns as my SQL column and the rest of the column should be pivot. My output should be: Please help me any idea ?

**Pivot table**

```
ID | Employee_ID | 01-sep-2019 | 02-sep-2019 | 03-sep-2019
───┼─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼────────────
1  | 1001        | P           | A           | P             
2  | 1002        | A           | P           | A           
3  | 1003        | A           | P           | P
```

**Original table**

```
ID | Employee_ID |STATUS | Created_Date
───┼─────────────┼───────┼─────────────
1  | 1001        | P     | 01-sep-2019
2  | 1002        | A     | 02-sep-2019
3  | 1003        | P     | 03-sep-2019
```

I use 2 `GridView to show data but it's applicable for all column that I don't need. Could you please help me?

```
private DataTable PivotTable(DataTable origTable) {
    DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;

    //Add Columns to new Table
    for (int i = 0; i <= origTable.Rows.Count; i++) {
        newTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(origTable.Columns[i].ColumnName, typeof(String)));
    }

    //Execute the Pivot Method
    for (int cols = 0; cols < origTable.Columns.Count; cols++) {
        dr = newTable.NewRow();
        for (int rows = 0; rows < origTable.Rows.Count; rows++) {
            if (rows < origTable.Columns.Count) {
                dr[0] = origTable.Columns[cols].ColumnName; // Add the Column Name in the first Column
                dr[rows + 1] = origTable.Rows[rows][cols];
            }
        }

        newTable.Rows.Add(dr); //add the DataRow to the new Table rows collection
    }

    return newTable;
}

private void BindGridView() {
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    try {
        con.Open();
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT Top(5)* FROM tbl_QC_Attandence";
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        DataTable dt = new  DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
            //Bind the First GridView with the original data from the DataTable
            grdorignal.DataSource = dt;
            grdorignal.DataBind();

            //Pivot the Original data from the DataTable by calling the
            //method PivotTable and pass the dt as the parameter
            DataTable pivotedTable = PivotTable(dt);
            grdpivote.DataSource = pivotedTable;
            grdpivote.DataBind();
        }
    } catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex) {
        string msg = "Fetch Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    } finally {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL TABLE**

ID  Employee_ID           STATUS     Created_Date

1   1001            P         01-sep-2019
2   1002            A         02-sep-2019
3   1003            P         03-sep-2019

**PIVOT TABLE**

ID           Employee_ID    01-sep-2019   02-sep-2019  03-sep-2019

1           1001            P               A           P
2       1002        A       P       A
3       1003        A       P       P[image: MY OUTPUT VIEW]

Comment: How can get this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have create a dynamic query which can help you, but null can be replaced with 'A' in code side, try below one

```
DECLARE 
@columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
@sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
@SelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

`SELECT 
    @columns += QUOTENAME([Created_Date]) + ','
FROM 
    Employee
ORDER BY 
    [Created_Date];`

`SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);`

`Select @SelectColumnNames = ISNULL(@SelectColumnNames + ',','')`
`+ 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([STATUS]) + ', 0) AS '`
`+ QUOTENAME([STATUS])`
`from (SELECT distinct [STATUS] from Employee) as Employees`
`print @SelectColumnNames`

`SET @sql =`
`N'Select * from(`
`select Created_Date,[STATUS],ID,Employee_ID`
`from Employee`
`)t`
`PIVOT(`
    `MAX([STATUS])`
    `FOR [Created_Date] IN ('+ @columns +')`
`) AS pivot_table`
`';`

`EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;`

[image]